# How do I code for nested inputs and save them into list?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

Sorry guys, I am still new and would like some help here.

I am trying to code the below... whereby it will have a user input that says:

**'Choose the number of brands interested between 1 to 20:'**

So answer can range from 1 to 20, and thereafter based on what was inputted earlier it will throw me input boxes to enter items which will go into a list.

**'Choose brand 1 from the following list:
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
FFF
GGG
...
LLL'**

So based on the first integer that was provided, it will throw me the 'n' number of input boxes for me to input. And the inputs ranging from AA to LLL will then be kept inside a list.

I came up with something below, but i am kinda stucked on how to implement the part where it throws the number of input boxes for user to input.

```
companies = []

while True:
    print('Choose from the below brands or enter nothing to stop')
    brand = input()
    if brand == '':
        break
    companies = companies + [brand]   #list concatenation
print('The companies are:')

for brand in companies:
    print(' ' + brand)
```

Comment: The code has ambiguous entries and missed many. Could you add the rest of code, plz? So, we can understand your code more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

First of, I'm confused. I'm only guessing you wanted the first part as follows,

Assuming you have your brands list ready.

```
brands = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF", "GGG"]
companies = []

while True:
    print (brands)
    print('Choose from the above brands or enter nothing to stop')
    brandindex = input()
    if brandindex == '':
        break
    else:
        companies.append(brands[int(brandindex)])
print (companies)
```

If I keyed in index 1,2 & 3, the following will be printed from "companies" list

```
['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF', 'GGG']
Choose from the above brands or enter nothing to stop
1
['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF', 'GGG']
Choose from the above brands or enter nothing to stop
2
['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF', 'GGG']
Choose from the above brands or enter nothing to stop
3
['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF', 'GGG']
Choose from the above brands or enter nothing to stop

['BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']
```

This is my guess of the first part. Don't quite understand why you are printing the `brand in companies` right after? Correct me from this direction.

Answer (score 0):

Do you miss a part of your code as your code doesn't do all the things you described?

- No input for 'Choose the number of brands interested between 1 to 20:' and the below code have nothing to do with that number
- No list containing brand from AAA to LLL

Below is a guess of what you want to do. I may edit it if you provide more information.

```
# get input for number of brands
number_of_brands = int(input("Choose the number of brands interested between 1 to 20:\n"))
# check if the number is between 1 to 20, keep asking input if out of range
while number_of_brands not in range(0,21):
    print("Please choose numbers between 1 to 20.")
    number_of_brands = int(input())

# a list from AAA to LLL
brand_option = [
    "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF", "GGG", "HHH", "III", "JJJ",
    "KKK", "LLL"
    ]

companies = []

# use for loop and range() to get inputs from 1 to 20 times based on input above
for i in range(number_of_brands):
    # string formatting to show current brand number
    brand = input(f"Choose brand {i+1} from the following list:\n{brand_option}\n")
    # check if the brand in option, keep asking input if not in option
    while brand not in brand_option:
        print("Please choose from the following list:")
        brand = input(f"{brand_option}\n")
    # append the brand if in option
    companies.append(brand)

print("The companies are: ")
for brand in companies:
    print(' ' + brand)
```

Sidenotes:

- are lowercase input acceptable like aaa, bbb and ccc?
- brand AAA to LLL are 12 brands only, so if the number of brands is over 12,
  the result will be repeated.
- would you like to have output like this?

  ```
    The companies are:
    brand1: AAA
    brand2: BBB
    brand3: CCC
    brand4: DDD
    brand5: EEE
  ```